# Convert byte array to encoded UFT8 in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, utf-8

I'm looking to convert a byte array to encoded UFT8 in Node. In Python, I've used the bytes() method to convert however I haven't been able to find a similar function in Node.

An example input would be `[0, 1, 66, 119, 208]` which would ideally return `\x00\x01Bw\xd0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js these days pretty much follows browser standards, as such the TextDecoder https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/TextDecoder  is part of node.

So this code below will work in browser or node.

```js
const r = new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array([0, 1, 66, 119, 208]));

console.log(r);
console.log(encodeURI(r));
console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
```

The question was asking for how to convert byte to utf-8.  The above does this.

The OP was more after a encoding compatible with C strings->
This repository looks like it should do the trick..
https://github.com/harold4/node-string-escape-for-cpp/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I ran the code snippet I got `\u0000\u0001Bw�`. How can I go from that to `\x00\x01Bw\xd0`

Comment: @Alex  so you don't want UTF8?.

Comment: maybe I incorrectly recognized the type of data I was looking for. What type of encoding would I use for that format? would it be ASCII? thanks

Comment: @Alex  That looks like C string escaping. And it should be possible to emulate,  just need to know what characters get hex, and what don't..  A simple lookup table would likely work here.  Some info here -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Comment: Found this that seems to have done all the hard work -> https://github.com/harold4/node-string-escape-for-cpp/blob/master/index.js